# Stuck with mysqli class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, scope

I am fairly new to object oriented programming with PHP and cannot figure out why the code below will not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public function connect() {
  $db = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->database);

  if ($db->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;}

  return $this->buildDB();
}

private function buildDB() {
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
        title   VARCHAR(150),
        body    TEXT,
        created   VARCHAR(100))";

  $db->query($sql);

  return true;
}
```

When executed I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\SimpleCMS\cms.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\SimpleCMS\cms.php on line 25

Comment: Your problem isn't with OOP, but rather with the scope of your `$db` variable (which only exists in your `connect()` function and not in your `buildDB()` function).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Oh no, another patronizing comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$db` variable is not in scope in `buildDB()`. You need to declare it as a member of the class so that all methods in the class can use it:

```
class DB {
    private $db;

    public function connect() {
        $this->db = ...;
        ...
    }

    private function buildDB() {
        ...
        $this->db->query(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are programming with classes. The most logical would be to have a variable that holds the connection. Like this:

```
private $db; // Variable to hold the database-connection

public function connect() {
    $this->db = new mysqli($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->database);

    if ($this->db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $this->db->connect_errno . ") " . $this->db->connect_error;
    }
    else {
        $this->buildDB();
    }
}

private function buildDB() {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (
        title   VARCHAR(150),
        body    TEXT,
        created   VARCHAR(100))";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$db` is not in scope for the buildDB function. Add the variable to your class:

`private $db;`

and replace all your references to `$db` with `$this->db`

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, got it sorted an appreciate the help!